# Change between 2 ethernet sources easily (without having to unplug anything)

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, router, ethernet

I just moved in a new house with very bad internet. At the moment we are using 2 different routers : a 4G router with good download and very bad ping, and an ADSL router with very bad download but a quite good and constant ping.

I would like to use the 4G router to download games and big files for my work, and the ADSL router to play competitive online games.

I would like to know if it is possible to plug both Ethernet cables to a piece of hardware, and easily change which one I'm using. Someone already asked a similar question a few years ago, so maybe something like this is possible now.

I have already used something similar to connect 2 HDMI sources to a monitor, but I didn't find anything for Ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hardware splitter devices for HDMI, audio etc. but I've never seen or even heard of one for Ethernet - there's never been really a market for them. You unfortunately didn't specify your operating system, so I'm assuming you use Windows.

If your system has 2 physical network interfaces, the easiest way is just to connect one to each router, and enable/disable the interfaces as needed. You can do this in the `Network & Internet settings` / `Change adapter options`:

[image: Win interface settings]

Alternatively you can use `netsh` -command in 2 .bat files:

For gaming:

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet1" disable
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet2" enable
```

For downloading:

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet2" disable
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet1" enable
```

Note - first disable, then enable. Check the correct interface names with command

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Or alternatively you can create a PowerShell script.

If your system only has one network interface things get more complicated. You could configure the routers to different subnets (for example 4G for `192.168.0.0/24`, ADSL for `192.168.1.0/24`), connect both to a hub or switch along with your PC, then use `netsh` or PowerShell scripts to change the IP addressing and DNS of your system.

I've never tried this myself. You will have 2 different DHCP servers on different ranges running in the same network, which is a *very* bad network design, but if you're the only one using the routers it should work. However if there are multiple users, every device needs to have a static IP connecting it to the router it's supposed to use...

So at the end, in multi-user situation just swapping the network cable as needed is the easiest solution. Using odd, non-standard network designs is never recommended, as they very easily lead to problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time. I use Windows most of the time and I think that your first solution is the best for me. PCI Ethernet adapter cards are cheap so I will buy one and change which interface to use with a script like you showed me.
Thank you for taking the time to explain and finding a solution to a specific issue, have a good day.

Comment: @AxelLudwig Glad to be of help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would likely have to change the metric in the Advanced Network properties for each adapter to change the adapter that is being used. This normally involves a restart.

This assumes you have two active Ethernet adapters which may not be the case.

Any way you choose to change Ethernet adapters programmatically will almost certainly require a restart. This will take longer than changing cables.

It is probably easier just to change Ethernet connections when you need to. This will be the simplest way.

Comment: Peregrino69's answer was more detailed but I thank your very much for your time, have a nice day.